# Is there a way to declare a specific type in ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ngFor to iterate a collection of a specific type [Menu] in Angular 4.x.

Then looping on a collection property of the menu object (*menu.items*).

Unfortunately, the property is unknown in my IDE ([Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) + Angular IDE), even though the Menu class defines the items property as an array of MenuItem.

Is there a solution?

[image: Red squiggles]

Relevant class declarations -

```
export class MenuBase {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  isPublic: boolean;
  roles: string[];
  items: MenuItem[];
  position: number;
// rest of class omitted
}

export class MenuItem extends MenuBase {
  menuItemType: MenuItemType;
  callback: () => void;
  location: string;

  constructor (options: any) {
    super(options);
    this.location = options.location;
    this.menuItemType = options.menuItemType || MenuItemType.location;
    this.callback = options.callback;
  }
}

export class Menu extends MenuBase {
  constructor (options: any) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```

#### Additional information

This is the project I was working on:
https://github.com/savantly-net/ngx-menu.
The project will show an error in Eclipse, even though it's valid.

I never created any documentation, but I used it here -
https://github.com/savantly-net/sprout-platform/tree/master/web/sprout-web-ui

Comment: It would be nice to be able to declare the type like *ngFor="let item: MenuItem of menu.items"

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: This is a known issue for AngularIDE. The code should still work if done correctly: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/t-does-not-contain-such-a-member-for-nested-for-loops/

Comment: I like the IDE to know the type information. It appears to know the first item, but not the type of the array property

Comment: Is there still not a solution for this issue? Just started learning Angular 6/7 and doesn't seem to be solved.

Comment: Note sure, but it was supposed to be fixed in the 2017 CI 9 release of Webclipse.

Comment: Note* this doesn't prevent the code from working correctly. I just don't like red squigglies in my IDE. =]

Comment: If you are using VS Code or WebStorm then this link may help you: https://angular.io/guide/language-service . Essentially, in VS Code, you install the extension "Angular Language Service" and then you get autocomplete in you `html` file. In WebStorm, you have to install it as a dev dependency `@angular/language-service`. You still cannot add a type but you will get autocomplete (which is why you need a type I assume) :)

Comment: Not a problem in the current version of IntelliJ, FWIW!

Comment: Is this for autocomplete or for compiling?

Comment: compiling works fine. This is for aesthetics and autocomplete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I've had success with is creating a new component for the template that the `*ngFor` will render and have that typed.

Container template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="item of items" >
  <my-custom-component [item]="item"></my-custom-component>
</ng-container>
```

Custom Component template:

```html
<div *ngIf="item.menuItemType == 'dropdown'">
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

ts file:

```
@Component({})
export class MyCustomComponent {
  @Input() item: MenuItem
}
```

Comment: It the same as that I did. Pass the model to a component and inside the component define it is a concrete type. Not sure if there are any better way doing it.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem with Eclipse ;) but I'll accept it as it works, and it's a good practice.

Comment: For anyone finding this: Do NOT use this approach IF you are planning to upgrade to Ivy as Ivy will fail during compilation due to type miss-match. We turned Ivy on in one of our apps that used the above and the entire app lit up like a Christmas tree with compilation errors.

Comment: Im not sure if we can advise to not use this approach as irrespective of this answer, the approach is generally good practice to use dumb / presentational components

Answer (score 2):

BTW: In Visual Studio Code, you need to specify it within the appropriate *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)* file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInputTypes": true,
}
```

Comment: strictTemplates option superseeded both options in Angular 11 or 12. https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe to work around this. This code was throwing a type error:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(item.value.value - defaultCssFilters[item.key].value) > 0">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

To fix it I used a pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(item.value.value - (defaultCssFilters | filterValue: item.key)) > 0">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

The pipe looks like this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filterValue' })
export class FilterValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(cssFilters: ICssFilters, key: TCssFilter): number {
    return cssFilters[key].value;
  }
}
```

This works because in the pipe you can declare your types.

When working with existing code, this is far less cumbersome than creating a new component.