# How to type a variable for ngfor for html template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have this variable in my component:

```
  sizes: {[key: string]: GoodModel[]};
```

And in the controller my IDE handle this well. For instance one can type:

```
  this.sizes['5'][0].brand;
```

Then you press f12 on brand for example and IDE shows the brand field of GoodModel class.

But it doesn't work when I do *ngFor in HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let size of sizes[radius]">
    <a [routerLink]="size.brand.url></a>
  </div>
```

IDE know nothing about size.brand and size.brand.url fields.

I think, maybe there is some way of handling it exist. Somethink like this:

```
  <div *ngFor="let size of sizes[radius] as GoodModel">
```

Is there a way of typing for this variable in HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new component for the template that the `*ngFor` will **render** and then you could have that **typed**.

Code from this answear: [Is there a way to declare a specific type in ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467551/15113491)

> Container template:
>
> ```
> <ng-container *ngFor="item of items" >
>   <my-custom-component [item]="item"></my-custom-component>
> </ng-container>
> ```
>
> Custom Component template:
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="item.menuItemType == 'dropdown'">
>   <!-- -->
> </div>
> ```
>
> `.ts` file:
>
> ```
> @Component({})
> export class MyCustomComponent {
>   @Input() item: MenuItem
> }
> ```